# Website shows white space on the right part of page

Tags: html, css

We are making a website in a team, and we struck at the famous white blank space in the right of page problem. We are looking for other possible causes.

In the homepage, there is a blank white part on the right for

- iOS(Iphone5 and Ipad, browsers are Safari and Chrome)
- Mac(Browsers are Safari and Chrome)
- Ubuntu(Firefox)

but, the same problem is not seen in the Android with chrome or Ubuntu with chrome.

We have tried the following suggestions in the StackOverflow, but no luck.

- Setting body and html margin and padding 0
- Setting img width 100%
- Checking font sizes(most of them is defined 1.2 rem)

Also, I have checked each layout in the dev tools, but none of them appears to exceed body width.

We have also tried to add an extra div after footer, or changing position:fixed to-the-page-top, but the result were the same.

Anyone have a sugguestion?

```css
     html, body, div, span,  {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        outline:0;
        font-size:100%;
        vertical-align:baseline;
        background:transparent;
    }
    body {
        line-height:1;
    }
    article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
    footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
        display:block;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style:none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes:none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content:'';
        content:none;
    }
    a {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-size:100%;
        vertical-align:baseline;
        background:transparent;
    }



    input, button, textarea, select {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
    }

    /*all-1.css*/
    @charset "UTF-8";
    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    body {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",  Meiryo,  sans-serif;
    }
    *, *::before, *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    font-family:'Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Arial',YuGothic,'Yu Gothic','Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN','ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3','メイリオ', Meiryo,'ＭＳ ゴシック',sans-serif;
    .tyousei{}

    .clearfix::after{
      content: '';
      display:block;
      clear: both;
    }

    .btn img{
      height:40%;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .btn .right-icon{
        position: absolute;
        top: 7px;
        right: 10px;
    }

    .btn::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left:0%;
      bottom:0px;
      display: block;
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #2F4D55;
      transition: all .4s ease;
    }

    .btn:hover::before{
      width: 100%;
    }
    #up-btn a{
      position: fixed;
      right:1%;
      bottom:40%;
      z-index: 5;
      opacity: 0.8;
      text-align: center;
      height:50px;
      width:50px;
      padding-top: 8px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color:#666;
    }

    #up-btn img{
      display: inline-block;
      width:65%;
      height:75%;
    }

    .header{
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 0;
    }


    .global-navi{
      height: 50px;}

    .logo{
      max-width: 250px;
      width:40%;
      min-width:200px;
      float: left;
      padding:20px 10px 10px 20px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4)
    }

    .logo img{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .form-top{display: none;}

    .sbox > *{
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .form .sbtn{
     width:34px;
     height: 28px;
     position: absolute;
     left:517px;
     top: 12px;
     border:none;
     font-size:20px;
     outline: 0;
    }

    .suggestion{
      border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
      border-right: solid 1px #666;
      border-left: solid 1px #666;
      z-index:10;
    }
    .suggestion:hover{
      background-color: rgba(240,240,240,1);
    }

    .word-suggestion{
       width: 236px;
       height: 30px;
       font-size: 16px;
       text-align: left;
       padding: 7px 5px;
       background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
       color:#333;
    }
    .article-suggestion{
    width: 350px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size:16px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

    .article-suggestion-title{
      position: relative;
      height:18px;
      overflow:hidden;
      font-weight:normal;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      line-height:18px;
      margin-bottom:12px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      color:#333;
    }

    .article-suggestion-desc{
      position: relative;
      height:30px;
      overflow:hidden;
      font-size:14px;
      line-height: 16px;
      color: #666;
      padding-left:6px;
    }
    .article-suggestion-desc::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top:0px;
      left:0px;
      width:3px;
      height:100%;
      background-color: #74c0d5;
    }
    .article-number{
      width: 350px;
      height:30px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
      z-index:20;
      font-size:14px;
      color:#666;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 7px;
    }
    .result{
      position: absolute;
      top:41px;
      left:282px;
      z-index: 20;
    }

    #no-result{
      width: 350px;
      height:210px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
      border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
      border-right: solid 1px #666;
      border-left: solid 1px #666;
      font-size:16px;
      line-height:20px;
      padding:10px;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    #no-result .kobetuba-mail-link{
      display: block;
      width:80%;
      height:60px;
      text-align: center;
      margin:10px auto 5px;
      border: solid 1px #666;
      padding: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 3px;
      position: relative;
    }
    #no-result .kobetuba-mail-link img{
      height:32px;
    }
    #no-result .kobetuba-mail-link p{
      font-size: 16px;
      color:#666;
    }
    #no-result .right-icon{
      position: absolute;
      top:15px;
      right:5px;
      color:#666;
    }

    #no-result .kobetuba-mail-link:hover{
      background-color: rgba(230,230,230,0.6)
    }

    @media (min-width: 800px){
      .form-top{
        display: block;
        position:relative;
      }
    }

    .navi-box{
      float:right;
    }
    .navi{
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding: 5px 2px;
    }


    @media (max-width:365px){
      .article-and-toiro{
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width:768px){
      .article-and-toiro p
      {font-size:16px;}
    }


    .message-box :hover{
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
    .account :hover{
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    .article-and-toiro:hover {
      background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    }
    .navi-icon a{
      position:relative
    }
    .navi-icon span{
      display: inline-block;
      top: -45px;
      left: 30px;
      width:20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
      position:absolute;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 20px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size:16px;
    }
    .wrapper {
      width: 96%;
      min-width: 320px;
      max-width: 1200px;
      padding-bottom:50px;
      margin: 10px auto 20px;
    }

    footer{
      display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width:800px){
    footer{
        display: block;
    }
    footer{
      box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}

    .footer-bottom {
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      height:44px;
      border-top:double #2F4D55;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding-top: 5px;
      /*background-color:#2F4D55;*/

    }
    .footer-bottom.close{
    box-shadow: 0px -6px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);}
    .footer-bottom img{
      height:70%;
      display: block;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .footer-open{
      width:100%;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color:#fff;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .footer-bottom.open{
      border-top:solid 1px #696969
    }

    .category-list-bottom {
      width:100%;
      position: fixed;
      top:0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left:0px;
      right:0px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      height:100%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
      box-shadow: 0px -6px 8px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
    }
    .category-list-bottom{
    }
    .close-btn{
      height:30px;
      background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.3)
    }
    .down-icon{
      color: #666;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .form-bottom{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom:10px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .form .sbtn{
      position: absolute;
      top:41px;
      left:10px;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      border-radius:20px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border:solid 2px #2F4D55;
      color:#737575;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .category-list-bottom .form-bottom{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .form .sbox{
      position:absolute;
      top:18px;
      right:11%;
      left:2%;
      width:85%;
      height:44px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border:solid 1px #535353;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .form .sbtn{
      position: absolute;
      top:20px;
      right:2%;
      left:88%;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .result-word-suggestion{
      position: absolute;
      top:64px;
      right: 11%;
      left: 3%;
      width:85%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .result-article-suggestion{
      position: absolute;
      top:64px;
      right: 11%;
      left: 2%;
      width: 95%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .form-bottom .word-suggestion{
        width:100%;
        height: 64px;
        /* font-size: 16px; */
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: #f2fbfd;
    }
    .form-bottom .article-suggestion{
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #f2fbfd;
    border-left:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-right:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .form-bottom .article-number{
    width:100%;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f2fbfd;
    border-left:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-right:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .form-bottom .article-suggestion:hover,.form-bottom .article-number:hover{
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }
    #form-bottom-no-result{
      width:100%;
      z-index: 100;
      background-color: #f2fbfd;
      border-left:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      border-right:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      border-bottom:solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #666;
      text-align: left;
    }
    #form-bottom-no-result .kobetuba-mail-link{
      display: block;
      width:95%;
      margin:10px auto 5px;
      height:70px;
      padding: 3px;
      border: solid 1px #666;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-size:16px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    #form-bottom-no-result .kobetuba-mail-link img{
      max-height:60%;
      max-width:95%;
    }
    #form-bottom-no-result .kobetuba-mail-link .right-icon{
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      right:10px;
      color:#666;
    }
    #form-bottom-no-result .kobetuba-mail-link:hover{
      background-color: rgba(230,230,230,0.4)
      }
    .category-list-bottom .category-list-wrapper{
      padding:55px 7px 7px;
      text-align: left;
      min-height:370px;
      height:90%;
    }


    .category-list-bottom .category-list{
      margin-top:5px;
      margin-bottom:5px;
      position: relative;
      height:35%;
      border:solid 1px #acabab;
      border-bottom:solid 2px #2F4D55;
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
    }

    .category-list-bottom .category-list-img{
      position:absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      padding-top:2px;
      padding-bottom:2px;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .category-mini-list-wrapper li{
      height:44px;
      list-style: none;
      margin:6px 10px 6px 10px;
      padding:12px 7px;
      background-color: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
      border-radius: 7px 22px 22px 7px;
      zoom:0.8;
      position: relative;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .article .category-mini-list-wrapper li{
      display: inline-block;
      width:47%;
      margin-top:3px;
      margin-bottom:3px;
      margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .right-icon{
      color:#666;
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      right:5px;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }

    .category-list-bottom .category-list.torio{
      height:25%;
      border-radius: 3px 22px 22px 3px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .category-list-bottom .category-list.torio img{
      zoom:0.8;
    }
    .category-list-bottom .category-list.torio .new-icon{
      margin-top:40px;
      padding-left: 160px;
      width:210px;
    }
    .category-list.all-close{
      height:35%;
    }
    .category-list.close{
      height:30%;
      min-height:80px;
    }
    .category-list.close .category-mini-list-wrapper,.category-list.all-close .category-mini-list-wrapper{
      display: none;
    }
    .category-list.open{
      height:auto;
      border:none;
    }
    .category-list.open .category-list-img{
      display:block;
      position:relative;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      transform:none;
      margin:5px auto;
    }
    .category-list.open .right-icon{
      display:none;}
    .category-list.open .category-mini-list-wrapper{
    display:block}

    @media (max-width:500px){
      .category-list.close{height:44px}
    }

    @media (max-width:346px){
      .category-list-bottom .article .category-mini-list-wrapper li{
        display: inline-block;
        width:45%;
      }
      .category-list-bottom .article .category-mini-list-wrapper img{
        zoom:0.9;
      }
    }
    @media(min-width:500px){
      .category-list-bottom .kobetuba .category-mini-list-wrapper li{
        display: inline-block;
        width:46%;
        margin-top:3px;
        margin-bottom:3px;
      }
      .category-list-bottom .kobetuba .category-mini-list-wrapper img{
        zoom:0.9;
      }
    }
    /* hp_style-1.css */
    @charset "UTF-8";
    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #333;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",  Meiryo,  sans-serif;
    }
    *, *::before, *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
      color: #7C5119;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue','Helvetica','Arial',YuGothic,'Yu Gothic','Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN','ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3','メイリオ', Meiryo,'ＭＳ ゴシック',sans-serif;
    .header{
      width: 100%;
    }
    .main-visual{
          height: 250px;
          background-image: url(../img/main-visual-mini.jpg);
          background-position: center center;
          background-size: cover;
          position: relative;
        }
    #vision{
      padding:10px;
      position: absolute;
      top:40%;
      right:2%;
      width:45%;
      min-width:270px;
      max-width:450px;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    @media(max-width:568px){
      #vision{background-color: rgba(237,231,221,0.8)}
    }
    @media (min-width:500px){
        .main-visual{
          background-image: url(../img/main-visual.jpg);}
    }
    @media (min-width: 800px){
      .main-visual{
      height:450px;
      background-image: url(../img/main-visual.jpg);
      position: relative;
      background-position: center;
    }
      #vision{
        background-color: transparent;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1020px){
      #vision{
        top:30%;
        width:55%;
        left:55%;
      }
    }
    .sbox{
      border:solid 1px #535353;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
    }
    .form .sbtn{
     color:#999;
      /*ここから臨時対応*/
     border-leftsolid 1px #737575;
    }
    .sbtn:hover{
      color#151e76;
    }
    .suggestion{
      border:none;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #666;
    }
    .suggestion:hover{
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    }
    .word-suggestion{
       background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }
    .article-suggestion{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    }
    #no-result{
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)
    }
    .message-box :hover{
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .account :hover{
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .category-navi{
      display: none;
    }
    /*タブレット縦以降*/
    @media (min-width: 801px){
      .category-mini-list{
        list-style-type:none;
      }
      .category-navi{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        border-bottom:double #022567;
        font-size: 0;
        padding-left:5%;
        padding-right:5%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .category-list {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        top:0px;
        min-width: 130px;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 16%;
        padding-right: 16%;
      }
    .category-list-button{
      position:absolute;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 280px;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right:0;
      margin: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
      .category-list-img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%)translateY(-50%);
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        margin: auto;
      }
    .category-list.toiro .category-list-img {
        top: 50%;
      }
    .category-list:hover{
        background:rgba(116,192,213,0.3);
      }
      .category-mini-list-wrapper{
        display: none;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        position: absolute;
        bottom:50px;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:192px;
        opacity: 0.9;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .category-mini-list{
        width: 100%;
        padding:10px 15px;
      }
      .category-list-mini-img {
        width:auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height:auto;
      }
      .category-mini-list:hover{
        background: rgba(116,192,213,0.1);
      }
      .category-list.toiro .new-icon{
        margin-top:15px;
        padding-left: 55px;
        width:100px;
        height:40px;
      }
    }
    .wrapper{
      padding-top:20px;
    }
    section{
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
     @media (min-width: 920px){
      .wrapper{
      width: 90%;
      margin: 20px auto 40px;}
    }
    @media (max-width:800px){
      .recomend,.new {
        width:100%;
      }
    }
    @media(min-width:800px){
    .new{
      width:
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [mcve] (and that link has some great advice on how to narrow down a problem which often leads to people being able to solve it themselves).

Comment: We are going to need to see a reproduction of the issue you are having so we can see the code you are using.

Comment: Re edit: That is a **massive** pile of CSS, it is far from being *minimal*. There is **no** HTML, it is far from being complete. You need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't set the body/html width and height.

Try this:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I added

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

You should remove this line, if you need to scroll left and right.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, actually, appearently I cannot vote yet.

Thank for help! I will try to change overflow-x!

Comment: Thanks m8. Good luck.